# SQL says I'm giving three arguments but as far as I can tell I'm only giving two

Tags: python, sql

This is my code:

```py
    db = get_db()
    db.execute(
        'INSERT INTO user (email, key)',
        ' VALUES (?, ?)',
        (session["email"], session["key"])
    )
    db.commit()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> (session["email"], session["key"])

> TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

I can't figure it out. As far as I can tell, there are only two arguments. For reference, session["email"] and session["key"] are strings.

Comment: You're giving 3 arguments. Probably, you don't want to add coma after first part of expression.

Comment: You have a comma between the two strings, so they're separate arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not referring to the number of values in the tuple, but to the number of arguments being passed to `db.execute`. Those three arguments are

1. `'INSERT INTO user (email, key)'`
2. `' VALUES (?, ?)'`
3. `(session["email"], session["key"])`.

What should have been a single `str` argument `'INSERT INTO user (email, key) VALUES (?,?)` has been split (inadvertently or not) into two separate arguments.

If you omit the comma, the two adjacent string literals will be "fused" by the parser into a single string literal:

```
db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO user (email, key)'
    ' VALUES (?, ?)',
    (session["email"], session["key"])
)
```

However, that's bound to cause confusion somewhere down the road. The string isn't that long, and really doesn't need to be split across two lines. Since whitespace in the SQL command won't matter, you could use a single multiline string

```
db.execute(
    '''INSERT INTO user (email, key)
        VALUES (?, ?)''',
    (session["email"], session["key"])
)
```

or simply put the entire command on a single line

```
db.execute(
    'INSERT INTO user (email, key) VALUES (?, ?)',
    (session["email"], session["key"])
)
```

Comment: Also it's possible to use named style and pass `session` object as second argument: `db.execute('INSERT INTO user (email, key) VALUES (:email, :key)', session)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot that there's not supposed to be a comma between the two strings. Silly mistake. I'll also switch it to one line.

Comment: @OlvinRoght That depends on the library. Not every implementation of the DB API has to support all possible parameter styles.

Comment: @chepner, yes, that's true, but I suppose future researchers would have a chance to test this functionality with module they'd use.